# how to maintain encryption/decryption of Kubernetes Secrets in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, encryption, azure-aks, kube-apiserver

how to maintain encryption/decryption of Kubernetes Secrets in AKS. I referred this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/ but as per this link https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/ec780bf4-f724-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0 I am not sure whether this feature is available in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

Answer (score 0):

consider managing the secrets in azure key vault. Integrate AKS cluster with azure key vault to source the secrets when the pod is started.
Following link would be helpful --> https://medium.com/swlh/integrate-azure-key-vault-with-azure-kubernetes-service-1a8740429bea

Comment: Thanks @P Ekambaram, I already implemented this feature. But if I mounted the secrets to PODs those are added as plain text in etc folder. This is the reason to do encryption. It will be great help if you share a good tutorial

Comment: that is the default behaviour. if you dont want users to see those secrets then restrict them from getting into pod using RBAC